# Use Realm Query Results as UITableView Section Headers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, realm

I am trying to use results from a Realm query as section headers in a UITableView.

Realm classes:

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var personId = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var surname: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var mobileNumber: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var password: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "personId"
    }
}

class Category: Object {
    @objc dynamic var categoryId = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var person: Person?
    @objc dynamic var categoryName: String = ""
    let categoryContent = List<String>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "categoryId"
    }
}
```

My code:

```
class HomeController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var itemsInSections: Array<Array<String>> = [["1A"], ["2A"], ["3A"], ["4A"], ["5A"], ["6A"], ["7A"], ["8A"], ["9A"], ["10A"]]  //Test content to figure out later

    @IBOutlet weak var tableDetails: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableDetails.dataSource = self
        tableDetails.delegate = self
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return getCategoryNames().count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsInSections[section].count
    }

    private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> [String] {
        return getCategoryNames()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath)
        let text = self.itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = text

        return cell
    }

    func getCategoryNames() -> [String] {
        let categoryNames = realm.objects(Category.self).filter("person.mobileNumber == %@", mobileNumber).map({$0.categoryName})
        return Array(categoryNames)
    }

}
```

The number of sections works perfectly, but the section headers are blank.

If I add:

```
print(Array(categoryNames))
```

to the getCategoryNames function, it returns ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4"] several times.  This seems to be the correct format for the string that is required for the section headers, but the table header is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let nameArr = getCategoryNames()
    return nameArr[section]
}
```

Function: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? so you need to return string for a particular section.

Comment: not yet.  I get "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'" error in my if let nameArr line.  My getCategoryNames() is returning [String]

Comment: Have you removed the if statement from the function? Just clean your code and run your app once.

Comment: Now I just need my table to update when I add a new Category....

Comment: Just reload your table view when you add a new category. tableView.reload()

Comment: Adding a new category is in a different View Controller...  Can I do it in ViewWillAppear or similar?

Comment: so when you come back reload your table view inside viewwillappear() method

Comment: Doesn't work.  I have a button on the HomeController which opens a Modal screen with an unwind segue back to my HomeController when the "Add New Category" button is pressed.  I think the unwind segue doesn't trigger ViewWillAppear?

Comment: yes It will not call, if you open model window in full screen then ViewWillAppear will get called.

Comment: That works.  For a consistent UI I would like my Add screen to be a popover, how can I then trigger the table update?

Comment: you have to implement model screen delegates and work on that...search about the you will get more info about that.