# Customise Table Header defined in func

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My table headers are being retrieved from Realm as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000245/use-realm-query-results-as-uitableview-section-headers/60000466).

Now I am trying to add a button to each header which will allow me to enter an edit mode.  I have a Prototype cell in my storyboard table with a reference to class "HomeTableHeader", and my HomeTableHeader.swift, for testing purposes, is:

```
class HomeTableHeader: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Also, I have a button added to the prototype cell in storyboard, bu this button doesn't show.

This file is not being referenced, the background color does not change.  Do I need to move my code to define the Header Title to the HomeTableHeader.swift file, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement your own custom section header you should follow this steps:

1. You must create your own view, either programmatically or using xib file. For creating view programmatically please refer to this [link](https://blog.usejournal.com/custom-uiview-in-swift-done-right-ddfe2c3080a) and for creating view with xib file please refer to this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960).
2. If your view will implement any user interaction, such as pressing a button make sure that you use **delegation pattern** to be notified when button was touched. Not familiar with delegation pattern? Refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5).
3. When you have your view setup, you can use it with table view delegate method called `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` which will create header view for every section. You can find documentation for this method over [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview).

Comment: .xib file for the view?  Not a .swift file? @luka-cefarin

Comment: Yeah sure, matter of fact every view can be created with .xib file and then loaded from there. For example you could use it to create your custom cell in table view. It really depends on your skills.